# Gathering data from every row in html table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I need to gather every single data in row from this table, with add-button I can add more rows, every row has a product name price quantity, can someone help me gather every single data from this table to a sqldatabase?

```
<form method="post" id="allData">
    <table id="jsondata" style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">            
        <thead>
        Pavadinimas: <input id="pavadinimas" type="text" name="pavadinimas">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Prekes pavadinimas</th>
                <th>Kiekis</th>
                <th>Kaina</th>
                <th>Suma</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="data">
        <tr id="prekes">
            <th><a href="#" id="down">Down</a> <a href="#" id="up">Up</a></th>
            <th><input id="preke" type="text" placeholder="Prekes pavadinimas" name="prekes_pav"></th>
            <th><input id="kiekis" type="text" placeholder="Kiekis" name="kiekis"></th>
            <th><input id="kaina" type="text" placeholder="Kaina" name="kaina"></th>
            <th>Suma</th>
            <th><a href="#" id="remRow">Remove</a></th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <button type="submit" name="add-button" id="add-button">
        <span>Prideti preke</span>
    </button> </br>
    <button type="submit" name="save-button" id="save-button">
        <span>Issaugoti</span>
    </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: I tried but I did it work i guess, im a newbie so sorry if offended you guys some how
$('#save-button').click(function(){
 var pavadinimas = $("#pavadinimas").val();
 var preke = $("#preke").val();
 var kiekis = $("#kiekis").val();
 var kaina = $("#kaina").val();
 $('#jsondata > tbody  > #prekes').each(function() {
  var data = 'pav=' + pavadinimas + '&preke=' + preke + '&kiekis=' + kiekis + '&kaina=' + kaina;
  alert(data);
 });
 $.ajax({
  method: "post",
  url: "naujas.php",
  data: data, 
  success: function(data){
   alert("ura");
  }
 });

});

Comment: Try to add dataType to your ajax of your code

Comment: If I understood you, you need to gather all th-s from table with id jsondata?
Can you please update question with ajax call that you tried and write what happens?